# Retirar o último valor encontrado dentro de uma string

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, query, oracle

Preciso tirar uma média de condições de pagamento no banco de dados e me deparei com a situação em que a coluna de condição é uma string e ela pode receber valores de parcelas separadas por barra. Preciso pegar o último valor após a última barra, sinal de porcentagem ou o valor. Segue um exemplo:

```
select '28/30/56', '10%60%30%', '12 dias'
from dual;
```

A saída deveria ser: 56, 30, 12...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT substr('28/30/56',Instr('28/30/56', '/',-1) +1 ,2), '10%60%30%', '12 dias' FROM DUAL;
```

O `substr` pega um determinado "range" dentro de uma string, já o *Instr* busca a posição de um caractere dentro da "string", quando passamos -1 no último parâmetro ele busca de forma  invertida.